# Which Mobile js library to use?

Tags: backbone.js, zepto, jqmobi

I have a backbone web app that I am optimizing both for mobile web as well as for integration into an HTML 5 mobile app. As such, I am evaluating different mobile js libraries to use, and i am have a couple of questions.

---

1) According to this, zepto is actually slower than jquery on mobile devices, despite being mobile focused.

[www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html](http://www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html)

Am i missing something on why i should be using zepto?

2) jQMobi appears to be the fastest JS framework - should I be expecting weird bugs, etc if I do a swtchover?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using no lib because all of them sucks for me. And since i m not going to support firefox and multiple version of ie, i can do a lot with native javascript(selector, css3 animations, ...)

1. Yes zepto is slower, but smaller in size, which lead to faster page load. Less bandwidth and Less parsing time. good for mobile website not mobile htm5 app
2. I checked [jqMobi demo](http://jqmobi.com/testdrive) in iphone 4 and that was not as smooth as i want. Also i could not  create my layout.

Additional point: Use [Turbolink](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) idea for mobile website, it is simple and effective